# Zurb Foundation Emails link to remote hosted Fonts

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, webfonts

I'm working on a newsletter with the boilerplate [zurb foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html) and trying to **link to externally hosted fonts**.

But it seems like, the links get lost because all styles get inlined. So my question is, **how I properly link to remotely hosted fonts?** I assume there needs to be a way to not inline all of the CSS.

---

### Minor Update

I added the `<style>` tag with the needed font links (`@font-face`) in the processed *.html* file, after running `npm run build`. **This works**, but I don't think that's the most convenient approach and I think there would be a more elegant way to accomplish custom hosted fonts.

---

### First Approach

I tried to add a `<style>` tag with links, in form of a linked html file *partials/fonts.html*, just at the beginning of `<body>` inside of *default.html*, but nothing gets compiled into the final *.html*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {{> fonts}}
    <span class="preheader">{{description}}</span>
    <table class="body">
      <tr>
        <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
          <center>
            {{> body}}
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've also tried, to put the links inside of my *.scss* files. They also don't get compiled properly, because `@font-face` can't be inlined.

Comment: Is this a web page? You have a number of obsolete elements and attributes. And are you really using XHTML?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom CSS to the style tag so this is a valid approach. link tags are removed outside of the main sfyle tag.

But this will only work in email clients which support `style` tags and font-face declarations.